# I am able to count down to zero but i also want to be able to enter a negative number and have it count up to zero

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that allows for user to input any number between negative five and positive five then have the number selected count to zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int start;

    do
//Asking for user input 1-5
    {
        printf("Need Number to start the countdown (1 - 5): ");
//Receiving user input
        scanf("%d",&start);
    }
//while the number is less than the number 6
    while(!(start<6));

    do
//Begin countdown
    {
        printf("%d\n",start);
        start--;
    }
    while(start>0);
//Displaying the number Zero when done
    printf("0\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be on the CodeReview site, but to start with you have a problem in your initial input loop

```
while(!(start<6));
```

Will allow the user to enter a value like -1,234,567, so it needs to be

```
while(start < -5 || start > 5);
```

That said, in the simplest form you just need an `if` statement

```
if (start > 0)
{
    // code to count down
}
else if (start < 0)
{
    // code to count up
}
else
{
    print("All Done"); // user entered zero
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int start = -6;
    int increment;

//Asking for user input -5 to +5
    while(start < -5 || start > 5)
    {
        printf("Enter number to start the countdown (1 - 5): ");
        scanf("%d",&start);
    }

    increment = (start < 0) ? +1 : -1;
//while the number is not just past zero
    while(start != increment)
    {
        printf("%d\n",start);
        start += increment;
    }
    return 0;
}
```